# Android Studio Video not displaying or recording

Tags: java, android, video, camera

I am trying to record video using mediarecorder and display that video on other activity. It was working fine and the video was there but now a error is occuring that video cannot be displayed. Can someone help?

**Here my code :**

```
     captureButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                isActionDown = true;
                try {
                    if (isActionDown) {

                        initRecorder();

                        if (isActionDown)

                            prepareRecorder();

                        isPrepared = true;
                    }
                    if (isPrepared && isActionDown) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "startRecorder", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        isRecording = true;
                        mediaRecorder.start();


                    } else {
                        releaseMediaRecorder();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("onLongPress Error ", e.toString());
                }

                return true;

            }
        });

        captureButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        isActionDown = false;

                        try {

                            if (isRecording) {

                                if (mediaRecorder != null) {
                                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                                    releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                                    camera.lock();
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "MediaRecoderNull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                isRecording = false;
                                if (fileUri != null) {
                                    playVideo(getView());
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


    Uri fileUri = null;
    Uri ImageUri;
private void initRecorder() {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        camera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
    }


    private void prepareRecorder() {
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());
        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
            isPrepared = true;
            return;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }


    public void playVideo(View view) {
        Intent playIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), CapturedVideoActivity.class);
        playIntent.putExtra("videoUri", fileUri.toString());
        startActivity(playIntent);
    }
```

so on the next screen while displaying this occurs [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUByu.png)

Next screen code:

```
        VideoView mVideoView = findViewById(R.id.videoCaptured);

    videoUri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getExtras().getString("videoUri"));
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
    mVideoView.start();
```

Comment: Can you please provide any error stack traces?

Comment: E/onLongPress Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaRecorder.start()' on a null object reference

E/GraphicExt: GraphicExtModuleLoader::CreateGraphicExtInstance false

Comment: These come when I start to record